# How do you reference values of sliders in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I need to create some sliders based on number items in a vector:

ui code:

```
   library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(usl)

ui<-dashboardPage(skin="green",
                  dashboardHeader(title = "ADM Logical Capacity Planning Service",titleWidth = 350),
                  dashboardSidebar(

                    sidebarMenu(
                      menuItem("Visualize & Create Model", tabName = "visualize",icon=icon("area-chart")),
                      menuItem("Forecast", tabName = "capacity", icon=icon("line-chart"))    )
                  ),
                  dashboardBody(
                    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                                              .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
                                              background-color: #3c8dbc;
                                              }
                                              .menuItem .main-header .logo:hover {
                                              background-color: #3c8dbc;
                                              }
                                              '))),


                    tabItems(
                      tabItem("capacity",
                              fluidRow(
                                column(3,
                                       wellPanel(
                                         span("Given the growth rate, forecast the underlying dependent variable")
                                       ),
                                       wellPanel(


                                           # Create a uiOutput to hold the sliders
                                           uiOutput("sliders")
                                        ),



                                         # Generate a row with a sidebar
                                         #sliderInput("capacity", "Growth Rate in Volume:", min=0, max=100, value=0,post="%"),
                                         #br(),
                                         #sliderInput("add_capacity", "Add Capacity in %:", min=0, max=100, value=0,post="%"),


                                       br(),
                                       wellPanel(

                                         actionButton("calcbtn", "Calculate Forecast")
                                       )
                                ),

                                mainPanel(
                                  h4("Prediction"),
                                  verbatimTextOutput("forecast_summary"),

                                  h4("Available Capacity"),
                                  verbatimTextOutput("capacity_summary")

                                  #h4("Peak Capacity"),
                                  #verbatimTextOutput("peak_capacity")
                                )
                              )

                      ),
                      tabItem("visualize",
                              pageWithSidebar(
                                headerPanel("Logical Capacity Planning Dashboard"),
                                sidebarPanel(
                                  fileInput('file1', 'Upload CSV File to Create a Model',
                                            accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv')),
                                  tags$hr(),
                                  checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                                  fluidRow(
                                    column(6,checkboxGroupInput("xaxisGrp","X-Axis:", c("1"="1","2"="2"))),
                                    column(6,radioButtons("yaxisGrp","Y-axis:", c("1"="1","2"="2")))
                                  ),
                                  radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                                               c(Comma=',', Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'), ','),
                                  radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                                               c(None='','Double Quote'='"','Single Quote'="'"),'"'),
                                  uiOutput("choose_columns")
                                ),
                                mainPanel(
                                  tabsetPanel(
                                    tabPanel("Data", tableOutput('contents')),
                                    tabPanel("Create Model & Plot",plotOutput("plot"),verbatimTextOutput("PeakCapacity")),
                                    tabPanel("Model Summary",verbatimTextOutput("summary"))

                                  )
                                )
                              )
                      )
                    )
                    )
                    )
```

server code:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) 
{


  ###
  output$sliders <- renderUI({
    xv <- input$xaxisGrp
    # First, create a list of sliders each with a different name
    sliders <- lapply(1:length(xv), function(i) {
      inputName <- xv[i]
      sliderInput(inputName, inputName, min=0, max=100, value=0, post="%")
    })
    # Create a tagList of sliders (this is important)
    do.call(tagList, sliders)
  })



  ###

  observeEvent(input$calcbtn, {

    n <- isolate(input$calcbtn)
    if (n == 0) return()

    output$forecast_summary <- renderPrint({
      n<-pred.model()
      n<-data.frame(n)
      row.names(n)<-NULL
      print(n)
    })

    output$capacity_summary <- renderPrint({
      n<-pred.model()
      n<-data.frame(n)
      row.names(n)<-NULL
      #c<-round(peak.scalability(usl.model()),digits=0)
      available<-round(((c-n[1,1])/c)*100,digits=0)
      row.names(available)<-NULL
      print(paste0(available,"%"))

    })

    #   output$peak_capacity <- renderPrint({

    #    print(paste("Maximum Capacity: ", round(peak.scalability(pred.model()),digits=0)))

    # })

    output$plot_forecast <- renderPlot({
      df <- data_set()
      new_df<- pred.model()

      print(sliders)
      if (!is.null(df)){

        xv <- input$xaxisGrp
        yv <- input$yaxisGrp
        print(xv)
        print(yv)
        if (!is.null(xv) & !is.null(yv)){

          if (sum(xv %in% names(df))>0){ # supress error when changing files

            df1<-data.frame(usl.model()$fitted)
            colnames(df1)<-c("Model")
            df<-cbind(df,df1)
            Model=c("Model")
            #ggplot(df, aes_string(xv,yv))+geom_point(size=3,colour="blue")+geom_line(data=df, aes_string(xv,Model),colour="orange",size=1)+
            #geom_point(data=new_df,aes(new_df[,1],new_df[,2]), colour="red",size=10)+theme_bw()+theme(legend.position = "none")

            #max_capacity<-round(peak.scalability(usl.model()),digits=0)
            Ninety_Fifth_Perc<-quantile(df[,2], 0.95)
            #peak<-round(peak.scalability(usl.model()),digits=0)
            #available<-round(((max_capacity-Ninety_Fifth_Perc)/max_capacity)*100,digits=0)
            new_d<-pred.model()

            ggplot(df, aes_string(xv,yv))+geom_point(size=4,shape=21, fill="blue")+geom_line(data=df, aes_string(xv,Model),colour="orange",size=1)+
              geom_point(data=new_df,aes(new_df[,1],new_df[,2]), colour="red",size=10)+
              theme_bw()+theme(legend.position = "none")+geom_vline(xintercept=new_df[,1], colour="green",size=1.5)



          }
        }
      }

    })

  })

  ###pred function
  pred.model <- reactive({
    xv <- input$xaxisGrp
    yv <- input$yaxisGrp

    #latest_df<-do.call(data.frame,setNames(lapply(xv,function(e) vector(typeof(e))),xv))
    latest_df<-data.frame()
    new_df1 = data.frame()


    for(i in 1:length(xv)){
     ##xv[i]<-as.numeric(input$xv[i])

   # capacity<-as.numeric(input$capacity)
    #add_capacity<-as.numeric(input$add_capacity)

      df <- data_set()
      if (!is.null(df)){

         if (!is.null(xv) & !is.null(yv)){

            if (sum(xv[i] %in% names(df))>0){ # supress error when changing files
          #usl.model <- usl(as.formula(paste(yv, '~', xv)), data = df)

            #new_growth<-tail(df[,xv],1)*(1+capacity/100)
            new_growth<-quantile(df[,xv[i]],0.95)*(1+input$xv[i]/100)
            new_cap<-new_growth

            new_df1[1,i] = setNames(data.frame(new_cap),xv[i])

            row.names(new_df1)<-NULL
            }
         }
      }
    }
    latest_df=new_df1

    prediction<-predict(usl.model(),newdata = latest_df)
    prediction<-data.frame(prediction)
    prediction<-prediction[1,1]

    return(prediction)
})
  ##end of pred function

  ###visualize section
  dsnames <- c()

  data_set <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    data(specsdm91)
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(specsdm91)

    data_set<-read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, 
                       sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote,stringsAsFactors=F)
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({data_set()})

  observe({
    dsnames <- names(data_set())
    cb_options <- list()
    cb_options[ dsnames] <- dsnames  
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "xaxisGrp",
                       label = "X-Axis",
                       choices = cb_options,
                       selected = "")
    updateRadioButtons(session, "yaxisGrp",
                             label = "Y-Axis",
                             choices = cb_options,
                             selected = "")
  })
  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    selectInput("dataset", "Data set", as.list(data_sets))
  })

  usl.model <- reactive({

    df <- data_set()
    if (!is.null(df)){

      xv <- input$xaxisGrp
      yv <- input$yaxisGrp
      print(xv)
      print(yv)
      if (!is.null(xv) & !is.null(yv)){

        if (sum(xv %in% names(df))>0){ # supress error when changing files
          xv <- paste(xv, collapse="+")

          lim <- lm(as.formula(paste(yv, '~', xv)), data = df)

          return(lim)

        }
      }
    }
  })


  ##plot
  output$plot = renderPlot({

    df <- data_set()
    if (!is.null(df)){

      xv <- input$xaxisGrp
      yv <- input$yaxisGrp
      print(xv)
      print(yv)
      if (!is.null(xv) & !is.null(yv)){

        if (sum(xv %in% names(df))>0){ # supress error when changing files

          #plot(as.formula(paste(yv, '~', xv)), data = df, pch = 21)

          #plot(usl.model(),add=TRUE)

          df1<-data.frame(usl.model()$fitted)
          colnames(df1)<-c("Best_Fit_Model")
          #df<-cbind(df,df1)
          Model<-c("Best_Fit_Model")
          df1<-cbind(df[yv],df1)

          #max_capacity<-round(peak.scalability(usl.model()),digits=0)
          #Ninety_Fifth_Perc<-quantile(df[,2], 0.95)
          #peak<-round(peak.scalability(usl.model()),digits=0)
          #available<-round(((max_capacity-Ninety_Fifth_Perc)/max_capacity)*100,digits=0)
          #new_d<-pred.model()
          df.melt=melt(df, id=yv) 
          xx<-c("value")

          ggplot(df.melt,aes_string(x = xx, y = yv)) + geom_point() +facet_wrap(~variable, scale="free")+theme_bw()+
            geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F, colour="red")

         # p2<-ggplot(df1,aes_string(x = yv, y = Model)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()+
          #  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F, colour="red")



        }
      }
    }

  } )

  ##
  output$summary <- renderPrint({

    summary(usl.model())

  }) 


  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({

    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()
    colnames <- names(contents)
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       selected = colnames)
  })


}
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: You're also referencing `xaxisGrp` as an input (which it isn't). That's causing some issues. Turns out fixing that (see the example below) makes things work nicely. I didn't realize that! Cool stuff.

Updating based on your comment, you should be able to access each input using bracket notation. Your question is still referencing `input$xaxisGrp` which doesn't exist, though. I'm also not sure why you're calling `renderPlot({})` since nothing's being plotted.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         uiOutput("sliders")
      ),
      mainPanel(

   )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  xaxisGrp <- c("CPU", "Memory", "Disk")

  output$sliders <- renderUI({
    xv <- xaxisGrp
    sliders <- lapply(1:length(xv), function(i) {
      inputName <- xv[i]
      sliderInput(inputName, inputName, min=0, max=100, value=0, post="%")
    })
    do.call(tagList, sliders)
  })

  output$plot_forecast <- renderPlot({
    xv <- xaxisGrp

    for(i in 1:length(xv)) {
      value <- input[xv[i]]
    }
  })
})
```

---

I'm a little unsure why you're constructing the sliders this way. Have you looked into [namespacing](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)? Or even just write 3 separate outputs? For example (you can run this to see each input `<key, value>` pair):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         uiOutput("slider1"),
         uiOutput("slider2"),
         uiOutput("slider3"),
         uiOutput("sliders")
      ),
      mainPanel(
         verbatimTextOutput("inputVals")
      )
   )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$slider1 <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("CPU2", "CPU2", min=0, max=100, value=0, post="%")
  })

  output$slider2 <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("Memory2", "Memory2", min=0, max=100, value=0, post="%")
  })

  output$slider3 <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("Disk2", "Disk2", min=0, max=100, value=0, post="%")
  })

  output$sliders <- renderUI({
    xv <- c("CPU","Memory","Disk")
    sliders <- lapply(1:length(xv), function(i) {
      inputName <- xv[i]
      sliderInput(inputName, inputName, min=0, max=100, value=0, post="%")
    })
    do.call(tagList, sliders)
  })

  output$inputVals <- renderPrint({
    print(reactiveValuesToList(input))
  })
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In your case, it looks like your inputs are all rendering without any ID (`xaxisGrp` isn't a valid input in your example). That's bad, they each need a unique one. Namespacing is one way to solve for this by abstracting the UI-generating functions and guarantee unique IDs for each input. Less cumbersome most times (unless, I don't know, you need to dynamically generate them based on some external factor) is to just create multiple individual inputs.

Once you're building the inputs correctly, then to access any given input's value, just use the `input$inputId` syntax within any reactive context:

```
output$CPUValue <- renderText({
  input$CPU
})
```

Comment: this is the idea. I upload a csv file into shiny and I need to create slider for each column name which stored in xaxisGrp. I then create the slider with output$sliders section mentioned above. Next I need to extract values from the sliders and apply to a function to calculate some values. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yup, so fixing the `xv <- input$xaxisGrp` line should solve things. Just reference `xaxisGrp` directly in your function and then you should be able to access the inputs no problem. If you need to do so dynamically, you should even be able to use `input[xaxisGrp[n]]` where `n` is the index of whatever element of the vector you're accessing.

Comment: I used for loop to access the values of each slider. I've update the initial post. Would that work or I need to do it input[xv[i]]?

Comment: You'll need to use the bracket notation if you're passing the value of some other object as a column name. I edited my answer with a reproducible example.

Comment: Faulconbridge, I am getting this error: Single-bracket indexing of reactivevalues object is not allowed., can I share my whole code with you?

Comment: Go for it! But from the sounds of it it's just a syntax error: `xv[i]` instead of `xv()[i]` or something similar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115430/discussion-between-faulconbridge-and-user1471980).

Comment: I just update the original post with the whole code (ui and server). The apps does this. Upload a csv file, chose x and y values, and predict based on growth rate of sliders. Let me know what you think. Thank you